# How does ActiveDirectory cross-domain trust carry over to an LDAP query?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, plone

I am using LDAP inside Plone running behind Apache on RHEL5 to authenticate users against ActiveDirectory. This worked great until we implemented cross-domain trust. Now the LDAP client doesn't know how to authenticate against the other trusted domains so our other users cannot use the web service.

Is there a nice way for the standard LDAP client to discover the cross-domain trust and try to authenticate against those as well?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the begining of an answer :

It exists objects from the class '`trustedDomain`' called Trusted domain objects (TDOs) that represent each trust relationship within a particular domain. Each time a trust is established a unique TDO is created and stored (in the System container) in its domain. Attributes such as a trust transitivity, type, and the reciprocal domain names are represented in a TDO.

If I use '`LDIFDE.EXE`' which is an integrated windows server tool like '`ldapsearch`' on OpenLDAP to search for such object :

```
C:\>ldifde -f trustedDomain.lfd -d "cn=system,dc=dom,dc=fr" -r "objectClass=trustedDomain" -l cn
```

The result is :

```
dn: CN=mod.dom.fr,CN=System,DC=dom,DC=fr
changetype: add
cn: mod.dom.fr

dn: CN=soc.fr,CN=System,DC=dom,DC=fr
changetype: add
cn: soc.fr
```

I've got two trusted domains that I can query from the value of the '`CN`' attribute of this object.